# Initialize selected radio button (NSButton) group in AppKit

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, appkit

I have dozens of radio button groups, each with their outlets connected to their group IBAction.  They all function exactly as one would expect.

QUESTION:

But in my initialization (in the NSViewController) for the view, I go through each radio button outlet (in each group) and set its state (NSControlValueON/OFF), based on which button is actually the "ON" button.  Should that even be necessary?  Does setting the state of any in the group automatically toggle the others off, then call the IBAction?  Or is there a way to simulate a click on the desired radio button?

A useful method would be to provide ANY NSControl* in the group, with a desired tag, and have that radio button turned on, and the others turned off.

NOTE: my code is Objective-C, but I'll abstract a Swift answer, too!

Comment: Have you tried if setting the state of any in the group automatically toggle the others off? You can find the button with a tag with `viewWithTag:`.

Comment: YES!  And that DOES work!